# In Python ,why does it end up in recursion while accessing private attribute from getter() ,without using double underscore in getter()

Tags: python, oop, getter-setter, encapsulation, private-members

```
class Person():

    def __init__(self,name:str,height :float) -> None:
        #initialize
        self.__name=name
        self.height=height
    
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        print("Inside Getter")
        return self.__name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        print("New name being set")
        self.name = value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"({self.__class__.__name__}:{self.name},{self.height})"

p=Person("Sam",180.00)
print(p)
```

1.In the above code ,when I access the name without using double underscore inside repr() method, it calls getter and then calls repr(). I don't understand why getter gets called here. (Code works as expected when I use double underscore inside repr() too, only repr() gets executed )

Output for the above code is:

***Inside Getter***

***(Person:Sam,180.0)***

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2.Slightly modifying the above code when I also remove the double underscore from the getter()(now both getter() and repr() don't have a double underscore)

```
 def name(self) -> str:
        print("Inside Getter")
        return self.name
```

I end up with an recursion error. How did recursion take place here?

***in name***
***print("Inside Getter")
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object***

Comment: You get/access the name property/attribute in the `__repr__` method, why do you think the getter wouldn't be called?

Comment: I have a print statement in getter that never got executed, when I used (self.__name) instead of (self.name) in __repr__ method.

Comment: That's to be expected, you're getting a different attribute with a different name to your property/descriptor, the property is named "name" not "__name"

Comment: `name` is the getter. `__name` is a completely different attribute `__name`. If you get the getter in the getter, then you only get the getter in the getter and can get the getter while you get the getter, [dawg](https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/0ca36be035e2c8c79d6af4543c7a6990.jpg). — Same problem in the setter BTW, you just haven't encountered it yet.

Comment: Thank you @IainShelvington .I get it now. I thought name and __name inside getter  were same only difference is public and private . Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: There is no such thing as a private attribute in a Python class. Coders will tend to use leading underscore(s) to indicate that an attribute should be considered as "private" but that's merely a common convention

Comment: @DarkKnight then how come we still get an attribute error when we directly access like print(p.__name).

Comment: Because that's exactly what the `__` is for: name mangling to prevent exactly this naïve kind of access. You can still get to the attribute if you try just a little harder.

Comment: @ArmaanSahoo the important thing to understand is that **python doesn't have public/private**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the recursion, when you access `self.name` you are actually calling the property

```py
@property
def name(self) -> str:
    print("Inside Getter")
    return self.__name
```

so if you try to access `self.name` *within* the property, you'll have set up a recursive loop.

Typically, you'd use the `self.__name` attribute to store the data that you want to obfuscate behind getters and setters, so your class would look like this:

```py
class Person():

    def __init__(self, name:str, height:float) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
    
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self.__name # Get self.__name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.__name = value # Set self.__name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"({self.__class__.__name__}:{self.name},{self.height})"
```